# sockaddr_in undeclared identifier

Tags: c, sockets

I am following along with beej's guide to networking and it's been going REALLY good because I understand everything very well and he explains it great. however, when I want to test out some of the cool things he's showing me, it won't work!. :(

I am not sure where exactly sockaddr_in is declared but maybe somebody here will so help me out!

Here is what I have so far (testing out converting an ip in string form to an ip to a 4 byte integral and vice versa):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void)
{
  sockaddr_in sin;

  inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.2.1", &sin.in_addr);
  char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sin.in_addr, ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("%s\n", ip);

  return 0;
}
```

Again I am completely clueless as to where everything is so if it's something really stupid on my part, sorry!

Edit: I'm on a Linux Debian distro called Mint if that helps at all?

Answer (score 31):

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) says:

> The  header shall define the sockaddr_in structure

You have to include `<netinet/in.h>` and declare `sin` like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
^^^^^^
```

To find out why you need the `struct` keyword, see this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/impltypedef.html). Long story short, there's no implicit `typedef` in C.

Comment: that fixed my main problem! netinet/in.h -- noted down, thanks! nevermind about the other error i put in_addr instead of s_addr :p

Answer (score 6):

According to [ip(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) man page, you also need

```
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <netinet/ip.h>
```

Comment: read most of the description and didn't understand a lot of it, yet, but i will definitely use those man pages for future reference on simple stuff like this. thanks!