# sockaddr structure - (sys/socket.h)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, ip

Ive been reading the [sys/socket.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) all day and finally starting to understand it, and now starting to use it, however, I'm not sure why I can't assign a value to `sa_family` member of the `sockaddr` struct.

Specification `sockaddr` Structure:

```
struct sockaddr{
    sa_family_t   sa_family       address family
    char          sa_data[]       socket address (variable-length data)
};
```

Data Type:  `sa_family_t` - Unsigned integral type (2-4 bytes)

Values:

```
Name                Purpose                          Man page
       AF_UNIX, AF_LOCAL   Local communication              unix(7)
       AF_INET             IPv4 Internet protocols          ip(7)
       AF_INET6            IPv6 Internet protocols          ipv6(7)
       AF_IPX              IPX - Novell protocols
       AF_NETLINK          Kernel user interface device     netlink(7)
       AF_X25              ITU-T X.25 / ISO-8208 protocol   x25(7)
       AF_AX25             Amateur radio AX.25 protocol
       AF_ATMPVC           Access to raw ATM PVCs
       AF_APPLETALK        AppleTalk                        ddp(7)
       AF_PACKET           Low level packet interface       packet(7)
       AF_ALG              Interface to kernel crypto API
```

Which is a bit confusing since these values are `char` data types not an `unsigned int`.

Simple Test:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h> 

int main(void){
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("Socket Address Family: %s\n", address.sin_family);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

`storage size of ‘address’ isn’t known`

It should be printing out `Socket Address Family: AF_INET`... what am I missing here?

Comment: `printf("Socket Address Family: %s\n", address.sin_family);` That makes no sense. It's not a string.

Comment: That was exactly my point... but I already realized that it's a macro constant thats associated with the integer 2.... in the `socket.h` source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you don't include the definition of that structure. The structure `sockaddr_in` is defined in `<netinet/in.h>`. For more details, see: [sockaddr_in undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102453/sockaddr-in-undeclared-identifier)

Comment: I changed the `%s` to `%d` for integer and it outputs `2` now.... If I look in `<netinet/in.h>` I don't see where it associates it with number 2 though?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it seems although the structure is declared in <netinet/in.h>, AF_INET is a macro constant defined in socket.h with value 2. Here is the code from socket.h: http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/Linux/Kod/include/linux/socket.h.html

Comment: Yesssssirrrr you are the man, yea I was just looking in the socket.h source file. Thank you! thank you!

Comment: @JordanDavis Actually, the `sa_data` field only exists in the generic `struct sockaddr`.  In `struct sockaddr_in`, the IP address is in `sin_addr` while the port is in `sin_port`.  These fields have the bytes in network byte order (i.e. big endian), so you'll need to use `htons()` and `ntohs()` for the port and `htonl()` and `ntohl()` for the address to convert between network and host byte order.

Comment: @dbush I'm going to go with the "generic" default `struct sockaddr` not the `sockaddr_in` so when using the `sa_data[]` is that a combination of the addr+port ?

Comment: @JordanDavis You don't want to do that.  Aside from the `sa_family` field, `struct sockaddr` is an opaque structure which may be laid out differently on different machines.  Trying to write directly to `sa_data` is not portable.